# Create a Windows 8.1 Portable USB Drive that's bootable on a Mac

Tags: osx, portable, windows-8, usb, bootable

I am seeking a tool to create a bootable Windows 8.1 Portable USB Drive (similar to the Ubuntu live usb), that also functions on a mac (meaning it should contain the necessary drivers)

My problem is that I do not have access to a Windows PC, as the tutorial I have found requires.

I was hoping to use a software such as [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), but as stated on their website:

> UNetbootin can also be run from Mac OS X, but note that only PCs (not Macs) can boot the resulting live USB drives.

Is there a tool that creates a portable Windows 8 USB Drive that runs on OS X operating system?